# Filter some special characters

Tags: python, string

Until now, when a user is registering in my app, he can't create a username with special character. I do it like this:

```
if username.isalnum() is False:
....
```

But now I want to enable a list of special characters like: `! - _ $`.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: you want them to be replaced or just deleted?

Comment: I just want to detect them. If a special character is not on the list, it will return a message telling this character is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will print bad characters

```
username = 'test343!_$&^ffg'
character_allowed = ['!', '_', '-', '$']
for letter in username:
    if not (letter.isalpha() or letter.isdigit() or letter in character_allowed):
      print letter
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I want !

Answer (score 0):

this code will alert if bad characters are used and remove them.

```
a = "username$"
b = "! - _ $" #can be a string, list or set

#alert if bad chars
for c in b:
    if c in a:
        print c + " is a bad character"
        break

#short alert code
if any((c in a) for c in b): print c + " is a bad character"

#remove bad chars
for c in b: a=a.replace(c,"")

print a
```

Comment: I don't think it will work. For example I allow the character "$". If I enter as username "MyUsername_$", how to detect that "_" is a bad character and $ is ok.

Comment: $ is not ok as you wrote before and this code is working, just try it. @GrandGTO

Comment: In your example, I put the bad character on a list/variable. But I want to put right character on a list.

Comment: you can do it @GrandGTO , just try

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work ... Or may be I don't understand your code.

Comment: my code just checks if any of the bad characters `b` are in `a` and if any of them appears in a it alerts the user. @GrandGTO

Comment: Ok. So it is not what i am looking for. I want to check if any of chacteres are any special character. For each special character, if any do not belong to the enable list of special character, it raises an erreur.

Comment: That is what I've done, it prints when it founds a bad char @GrandGTO

Answer (score 0):

A invalid char is not alpha numeric `and` it's not in the allowed special characters.

```
name = 'GrandGTO$@'
valid_chars = set('! - _ $')

for char in name:
    if not char.isalnum() and char not in valid_chars:
        print(char, 'is invalid.')
        break
```